# Given the following state diagram, write out its formal definition as a 5-tuple

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

[image]

I got these for four of them, but I can't get the transition function.

Q = {q1, q2, q3, q4}

Σ = {a,b}

q1 is the start state, and

F = {q4}

Answer (score 2):

The transition function can be represented as a two dimensional array. For your automaton, you just need to complete the following:

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
& a & b\\
\hline
q_1& &\\
\hline
q_2& &\\
\hline
q_3& &\\
\hline
q_4& &\\
\hline
\end{array}$

It can also be defined as a set of triplets $(q, a, \delta(q, a))$ (for example $(q_1, a, q_2)$ can be a triplet of the set).